# Understanding two algebra steps in Altland & Simons

Tags: condensed-matter, greens-functions, propagator

I would like to understand two summations on page 184-185, where we are told that assuming $x > 0$:

$$ G_{\pm} (x, \tau) = - \frac{T}{L} \sum_{p, \omega_{\, n}} \frac{1}{- i \omega_n \mp p} e^{- i p x - i \omega_{\, n} \; \tau} \; $$
$$= \mp i T \sum_n \Theta(\pm n) e^{\omega_{\, n} \; (\mp x - i \tau)} \;$$
$$ \approx \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{\pm i x - \tau}.$$

How do we get the last two steps (the second equality and the approximation)?

The only comments the book makes is that for the first step we integrate over momenta, and the second is that we approximate the frequency sum by an integral. It's not clear to me how to perform these summations/integrals.

Comment: since here is one-dimensional, the second equality is just residue theorem. the final approximation is just sum of geometric sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Altland&Simons have in mind approximating both momentum and Matsubara frequency sums by integrals, which is permissible in the limits $L\to \infty$ and $T\to 0$ respectively. Introducing the spacings of momentum and frequency grids $\delta p=2\pi/L$ and $\delta\omega=2\pi T$ $$ G_{+} (x, \tau) = - \frac{T}{L} \sum_{p_m, \omega_{\, n}} \frac{1}{- i \omega_n - p_m} e^{- i p_m x - i \omega_{\, n} \; \tau} \;=\\- \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\sum_{p_m, \omega_{\, n}} \frac{\delta p\;\delta\omega}{- i \omega_n - p_m} e^{- i p_m x - i \omega_{\, n} \; \tau} \; \approx\\- \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{ -\infty}^{\infty} \delta\omega \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp\;\frac{ e^{- i p x - i \omega\tau}}{{- i \omega - p}} = \\ -\frac{i}{2\pi} \int_{ 0}^{\infty} \delta\omega\;e^{- \omega x - i \omega\tau} =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{ i x - \tau}.$$